# NSString to float with best precision possible

Tags: objective-c, xcode, floating-point

I have a NSString, @"48.23456789"
the floatValue method gives me "48.234568"

Is there a way to make it more precise ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: your means to round it 2 or 3 digits after decimal point.

Comment: Use double or NSDecimalNumber if you need more precision

Comment: With NSDecimalNumber I manage to get perfect precision, but I am stuck after that because I do not know how to use it. I use these numbers as locations, longitude and latitude, but maps can only manage floats or doubles. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `doubleValue` instead of `floatValue` to get twice as much precision.

Answer (score 4):

use `doubleValue`. Even better, use `NSScanner`:

```
NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"3.14159265358979323846"];
double applePie;
[scn scanDouble:&applePie];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I scanned the string @"48.8728575000734" and used exactly your code, but applePie is set to 48.872858.

Comment: @ThibL what is your test for discovering what `applePie` is set to?

Comment: @ThibL also note that if you print it using `printf()` or `NSLog()`, you have to set a sufficiently large display precision. These functions ain't magic.

Comment: @matt & H2CO3 : I surely did a mistake here. I only did a NSLog(@"%f", applePie);

Answer (score 0):

In fact my problem came from the way I printed my float (or double).

To print a precise float/double with NSLog.
Use this :

```
NSLog(@"float : %.8f", myFloat);
```

.8 determines the number of digits after the coma.